# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space after adding LIMIT in SQL query

Tags: java, sql, gridgain

```sql
SELECT * from <table_name> WHERE CONTENT_ID = '<content_Id>' LIMIT 1000;
```

Earlier this query was running fine without LIMIT clause. But after adding the LIMIT after a few run we are getting:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space

Note : Using GridGain

Help me understand this.

Comment: I don't know GridGain, but it looks like some VM config/tweaks may be needed? I found [this GridGain info](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/memory-tuning) if that may be helpful?

Comment: Could be a bug. Can you create a small reproducer program?